# xcodebuild 8.3.1 - Delay of 2min 15secs when launching app

Tags: xcode, ui-automation, xcodebuild, xcode8

I am seeing a delay of approx 2 minutes 15 seconds every time I attempt to run XCUI Tests using xcodebuild 8.3 (and also 8.3.1). I didn't see this issue in 8.2.1 or before.

The app eventually launches and testing begins as normal.

The whole process seems to stall at the point where the app should be launched and testing begins.

Is anyone else seeing this? Here are some partial logs of the point of delay:

> 2017-04-10 16:00:56.981 XCTRunner[15276:171799] Running tests...
>
> 2017-04-10 **16:00:57**.707 XCTRunner[15276:171799] Continuing to run
>   tests in the background with task ID 1
>
> Test Suite 'Selected tests'
>   started at 2017-04-10 **16:03:13**.442

This is the command I am running:

`xcodebuild test -workspace "PathTo.xcworkspace" -scheme UITests -sdk iphonesimulator10.3 -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6s,OS=latest'`

Seeing this in a loop multiple times per second in the Test Runner logs also while the delay is occurring:

> 16:03:08.593 XCTRunner[15276:171799] XCTWaiter: 0x610000014c40 cleaning up Expect predicate `BLOCKPREDICATE(0x60000044f060)` for object BLOCKPREDICATE(0x60000044f060)
>
> 16:03:08.593 XCTRunner[15276:171799] XCTWaiter: 0x610000014cb0 entering wait loop for 60.00s 16:03:08.690 XCTRunner[15276:171830]  watchdog first trigger, clearing _XCWaitLoopIsValid and waking other waiters
>
> 16:03:08.690 XCTRunner[15276:171837] XCTWaiter: 0x600000006fb0 watchdog second trigger, weakWaiter: (null) 16:03:08.694 XCTRunner[15276:171830  0x610000014cb0: cancelWaiting

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @JohnSlade No, unfortunately not. Are you seeing the same issue?